# What is the HTML entity for a search icon?

Tags: css, html-entities

I'm trying to put a search icon in the navigation bar of my webpage but I'm not willing to use image for the purpose. Is there a HTML entity for a search icon used in search engines or search bars in different websites. I know most of them use images but is there any HTML entity for it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am providing the code

```
<li><a href="#search"> **SearchIconEntityToPutHere** </a>
  <ul>
  <li><form id="searchbar">
      <input type="text">
      </form></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Unicode : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036038/is-there-unicode-glyph-symbol-to-represent-search or http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/128269

Comment: I also don't think there is an HTML enitity for that. for an icon I think you need an icon, examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945281/html-button-with-search-icon @Pauli_D good link!

Comment: Thank you so much. But unfortunately,it's not widely supported. Even my browser doesn't support these.

Comment: @Susan now it gets hard to help. please show the code you have so far which is not working. an icon is supported in every browser even yours

Comment: I have added the code. However,when I put the character entity provided by few users, I only see boxes. For example,when I put &#x26B2; it is supposed to show this symbol (⚲),but it doesn't.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**HTML**

Use `&#128269;` for 🔍 and `&#128270;` for 🔎

**CSS (content string)**

Use `'\1F50D'` for 🔍 and `'\1F50E'` for 🔎

As noted in comments, this depends on font and unicode support.

I suggest you stick with using an image or sprite sheet for this purpose to ensure that it's supported.

**Update: Fonts**

A new method for this is through the use of special font frameworks, which use a combination of web fonts and CSS helper classes. One example is [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) (the example below uses the [search icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/)):

```
<i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Using this method has the benefit of having something that can be resized without a change in quality, as well as being subject to CSS rules like any other text, so rules like `color` and `text-shadow` can affect it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I only see boxes. How do  I fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You make sure you are using a font that has a glyph for that character.

Comment: That you can't see them demonstrates the problem that people addressed in the comments. You need to be on an OS/browser that supports unicode and have a font that includes those characters. http://i.imgur.com/Yu1wjcu.png

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand now. I guess it's a better idea to use a png image for the purpose.

Answer (score 5):

How about using css and html only? This is what I did (can be improved):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
        <title> A css trick </title>
        <style type="text/css">
             body{
            background-size: 100%; 
            background-color: #000; 
            color: orange;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;         
            }
            #search_box{width: 60px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; transform: rotate(26deg)}
            #search{width:10px; height: 10px; border: 3px solid #f5f5f5; border-radius: 10px; float: left;}
            #cabe{width: 8px;display: block; border: 2px solid #fff;color: #f6f6f6; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 2px 0px #fff; position: absolute; top: 6px; left: 13px; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 10px;}

        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CSS TRICK</h1>
        <div id="search_box"><div id="search"></div><span id="cabe"></span></div>

    </body>  

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *HTML entity* that could be reasonably regarded as denoting a “search icon”.

Depending on what you mean by “search icon”, there may or may not be a Unicode character that represents it. See [Is there Unicode glyph Symbol to represent "Search"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036038/is-there-unicode-glyph-symbol-to-represent-search). If there is, then it can be written as a *character reference* in HTML, though this is rather immaterial; the important thing is that most fonts would not contain it.